# Suggest me to make relation between 2 document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying a build a system where User can issue a Book for a certain time.I have two document, User and Book.

> **User**: name, email. 
>   **Book**: title, genre, stock_qty

Now if a user issues a book for certain time, there will be a record of the book id, the user id, issue date, return date, return status. What is the right approach for this?

I thought of making a sub array of a document in the User document. But I found suggestion not to do that as it will be frequently mutable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the User collection as frequently as users order some books, you can create another collection, something like book_issues with fields user_id, book_id, issue_date, return date and return status and store that information there.